# Bootstrap-material-design carousel control partially working but got zone aware error

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4

I downloaded bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha6 manually and put bootstrap.min.js into assets/js, as well as tether.min.js and jquery.min.js. Also involved [Bootstrap-material-design](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design) as well. Using @angular/cli 1.0.0-rc0, by the way.

I simply just copy example carousel, and paste that in my app.component.html.

```html
<section id="recomSite" class="carousel slide col-md-6" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="assets/images/pica.jpg" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="assets/images/picb.png" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="assets/images/picc.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recomSite" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#recomSite" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </section>
```

It partially works as the picture does slide, but without any animation. And eachtime I press next or prev button, I get error in console.

> Uncaught :ZoneAwareError __zone_symbol__error: Error: Carousel is sliding
>       at h.next (http://localhost:4200/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:7449) [……}

Comment: can u create a plunker

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/vFIkcxByk37sDvrLsxdQ. It works fine in plunker.

Comment: so is it fixed or you need help?

Comment: @Aravind Thanks. I intended to show you how the error appears but unexpectedly it works well in plunker. The error doesn't show up in vanilla bootstrap, only in bootstrap-material-design. Now I've found a fix.

Comment: ok. cool. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

when linking [bootstrap material design](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design) library, only involve 
 `bootstrap-material-design.iife.min.js`. Do not link  `bootstrap-material-design.iife.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` simultaneously.

deleting the line

```
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

in index.html fixes this issue.